# Error messages shown while booting Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, boot

I see the following messages on booting. My system works fine. I have disabled the plymouth theme and I am using text boot only

> udevd[343]: SYSFS{}= will be removed
>   in a future udev version, please use
>   ATTR{}= to match the event device, or
>   ATTRS{}= to match a parent device, in
>   /etc/udev/rules.d/80-canon_mfp.rules:10
>   ^M udevd[343]: SYSFS{}= will be
>   removed in a future udev version,
>   please use ATTR{}= to match the event
>   device, or ATTRS{}= to match a parent
>   device, in
>   /etc/udev/rules.d/80-canon_mfp.rules:12
>   ^M udevd[343]: SYSFS{}= will be
>   removed in a future udev version,
>   please use ATTR{}= to match the event
>   device, or ATTRS{}= to match a parent
>   device, in
>   /etc/udev/rules.d/80-canon_mfp.rules:14
>   ^M udevd[343]: SYSFS{}= will be
>   removed in a future udev version,
>   please use ATTR{}= to match the event
>   device, or ATTRS{}= to match a parent
>   device, in
>   /etc/udev/rules.d/80-canon_mfp.rules:17
>   ^M udevd[343]: SYSFS{}= will be
>   removed in a future udev version,
>   please use ATTR{}= to match the event
>   device, or ATTRS{}= to match a parent
>   device, in
>   /etc/udev/rules.d/80-canon_mfp.rules:19
>   ^M udevd[343]: SYSFS{}= will be
>   removed in a future udev version,
>   please use ATTR{}= to match the event
>   device, or ATTRS{}= to match a parent
>   device, in
>   /etc/udev/rules.d/80-canon_mfp.rules:21
>   ^M udevd[343]: SYSFS{}= will be
>   removed in a future udev version,
>   please use ATTR{}= to match the event
>   device, or ATTRS{}= to match a parent
>   device, in
>   /etc/udev/rules.d/80-canon_mfp.rules:23
>   ^M udevd[343]: SYSFS{}= will be
>   removed in a future udev version,
>   please use ATTR{}= to match the event
>   device, or ATTRS{}= to match a parent
>   device, in
>   /etc/udev/rules.d/80-canon_mfp.rules:26
>   ^M udevd[343]: SYSFS{}= will be
>   removed in a future udev version,
>   please use ATTR{}= to match the event
>   device, or ATTRS{}= to match a parent
>   device, in
>   /etc/udev/rules.d/80-canon_mfp.rules:28
>   ^M udevd[343]: SYSFS{}= will be
>   removed in a future udev version,
>   please use ATTR{}= to match the event
>   device, or ATTRS{}= to match a parent
>   device, in
>   /etc/udev/rules.d/80-canon_mfp.rules:30
>   ^M udevd[343]: SYSFS{}= will be
>   removed in a future udev version,
>   please use ATTR{}= to match the event
>   device, or ATTRS{}= to match a parent
>   device, in
>   /etc/udev/rules.d/80-canon_mfp.rules:32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

udev rules for your cannon printer. If you open

```
cat /etc/udev/rules.d/80-canon_mfp.rules
```

You will see where it wants to substitute SYSFS{} for ATTRS{}